# Switch a button depending on check box selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I currently am building a form that has 3 checkboxes and a dynamic button that appears below.

My current issue is when you select more than one then tick off one more both the active state and deactivate state buttons appear

https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/demo-select/ here is my demo link

Here is the script im using

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).on("change", ".mod-link", function() {
  var arr = []
  $(".mod-link:checked").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
  })
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('#picture').attr('src', '');
    } else {
        $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/greyBTN.jpg');
    }
  var vals = arr.join(",")
  var str = "/demo/?demo_request_type=" + vals;
  var link = arr.length > 0 ? '<a class="dynabtn" href="'+str+'">Continue</a>': '' ;
  
  $('.link-container').html(link);
  
});

</script>
```

here is my html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="mod-link" name="selected" value="es" hidden>
<label for="checkbox1" style="cursor: pointer;">CHECK BOX styling and info  HERE</label>

<div class="link-container" style="text-align:center;"></div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
<span class="result_img">
      <img id="picture" src="https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/greyBTN.jpg"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

I would like to figure out how to hide the grey image button until ALL OR NO checkboxes are selected. so for short #picture should not display until ALL OR NO CHECKBOXES ARE SELECTED

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Please make a minimally reproducible example here

Comment: i updated the code to include the script all in one block

Comment: @s.kuznetsov let me know if this is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `arr.length` earlier for showing and hiding gray button as well. Please see below code:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).on("change", ".mod-link", function() {
  var arr = []
  $(".mod-link:checked").each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
  })
      if (arr.length > 0) {
      $('#picture').attr('src', '');
    } else {
        $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://staging-homecarepulse.kinsta.cloud/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/greyBTN.jpg');
    }
  var vals = arr.join(",")
  var str = "/demo/?demo_request_type=" + vals;
  var link = arr.length > 0 ? '<a class="dynabtn" href="'+str+'">Continue</a>': '' ;
  
  $('.link-container').html(link);
  
});

</script>
```

Hope it resolve your issue.